# Alter script execution to skip over line throwing error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

We have deployed code to a server where a line on our html page will throw an error:

```
 <script>
     $('foo .' + '').html() //kaboom
 </script>
```

This halts execution, preventing QA from doing their work. Is there some way before the next deployment to alter this line with Chrome's debugger tools to skip past it or alter this line so it won't error out and execution won't be halted?

Comment: If this is a QA server, I would say its easiest to just manually edit the file on the server and delete / comment that line. Either that or just rollback / patch the release quicker if possible

Comment: The html doc is compiled, unfortunately it just isn't plain text.

Comment: @dfsq I am aware, the server-side processing has a flaw whereby this invalid selector is being produced, which is the source of this issue.

Comment: You can try using "Pause on exceptions" and modify the code before it is executed.